# Css <ul> selector

Tags: html, css, css-selectors

What is the selector to reach the ul markups highlighted below?
(no class or id is possible  i need a selector to the html markup)

Here is my html code:

```
<div id="mainmenu">
  <ul class="menu">
    <li class="item-472">
        <a href="#">Accueil</a>
    </li>
    <li class="item-475 current active deeper parent">
      <a href="#" class="drop">Produits</a>  
        **<ul> <!--Here is the first ul I'm tryin to style --> **  
            <li class="item-519 deeper parent" >
            <h3>Fenêtres</h3>
            <p>PVC</p>
            <a href="#">Fenêtres</a>
           ** <ul> <!-- the second ul to style -->**
                <li class="item-521 deeper parent">
                    <a href="#">PVC</a>
                    <ul >
                        <li class="item-522"><a href="#">Arcade</a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
            </ul>
            </li>
        </ul>
    </li>
```

Comment: what are you trying to do? have you got any CSS?

Comment: Instead of concentrating on what to do in the particular situation, try using your browser's inspector. This will help you get a better handle on how to properly address elements.

Comment: Yes, I have a css. But nothing happens! When I use class in ul it works without any problem. The item classes are generated with joomla and I just need to adapt my css with it.

Answer (score 3):

There are a number of ways to style these unordered lists, depending on how specific you want your selectors to be. I have created a somewhat comprehensive list below.

Ways to select the first `ul`:

- `ul`
- `li ul`
- `ul li ul`
- `ul .item-475 ul`
- `ul .current ul`
- `ul .active ul`
- `ul .deeper ul`
- `ul .parent ul`

Ways to select the second `ul`:

- `ul ul`
- `li ul ul`
- `ul li ul ul`
- `ul .item-475 ul ul`
- `ul .current ul ul`
- `ul .active ul ul`
- `ul .deeper ul ul`
- `ul .parent ul ul`

**IMPORTANT:** Be sure that the second `ul` is either as specific or more specific than the first `ul`. Otherwise, the style of the first `ul` will be applied to the second `ul`.

For example, [this would work](http://jsfiddle.net/M3KRP/1/):

```
li ul {
    /* styles here */
}

ul .current ul ul {
    /* styles here */
}
```

But [this would NOT work](http://jsfiddle.net/M3KRP/2/):

```
ul .current ul {
    /* styles here */
}

ul ul {
    /* styles here */
}
```

Comment: @user2037471 Is there anything else I can help you with regarding this issue?

Answer (score -1):

first one:

```
li.active ul
```

second one:

```
li.active ul ul
```

http://jsfiddle.net/YYsZ3/

Comment: I tried everything, it doesn't work :(

Comment: sorry I thought those ul's were inside that `.drop` link, fixed it now..